# How do I compress an encrypted time machine disk image?

Tags: encryption, compression, disk-image, hdiutil

I have an archived read-only Time Machine drive sitting on a NAS. It is a straight dump (made with `dd`) of a CoreStorage encrypted HFS+ hard disk. It's taking up 10TB, and I expect that the much of the data is eminently compressible, but of course, being encrypted, things like `gzip` will not be able to meaningfully compress the file itself.

I would normally just try things myself before asking a question, but given the need for between 20TB and 30TB of scratch space to attempt this, I want to have a very good sense beforehand of whether this will work.

My requirements are:

- It should be compressed substantially more than it is in its 'raw dump' state.
- It must remain legible to Time Machine for restores and browsing.
- It must remain encrypted in some form.

Nice to have:

- It would be nice to be able to do this in a way that is both in-place and safely resumable.

  - In-place because I would really like to reduce the necessary scratch space on the NAS.
  - Resumable because while I do have a 10GbE nic in the NAS and 2.5GbE on my mac, but even at wire-speed just reading the image is 10 hours, and in practice going through the SMB and Btrfs layers to the actual disk, it is likely to take more like 30-40 hours just for a straight read and then write; it would be nice to be able to reboot in the middle and not lose progress if we have a power cut or something.

Non-requirements:

- I don't want the resulting file to be read/write.  In fact I plan to make the file itself read-only; this is historical data, not a live backup of a current computer.

My guess would be to do something like this:

```
hdiutil convert input.dmg -o output.dmg \
    -format ULMO \
    -encryption AES-128
```

so the question is: should I expect that to work, and to result in a usable disk image at this scale of data?

Comment: Encrypted implies high entropy. High entropy doesn't compress well.

Comment: As Tetsujin said, you can't really compress encrypted data; you need to decrypt -> compress -> reencrypt. I think the easiest way will be to mount the image (so you have access to the volume in decrypted form), then use `hdiutil create` to make a compressed, encrypted image from that. This will not be either in-place or resumable. (And I haven't tested it.)

Comment: This is what I meant by "of course, being encrypted, things like gzip will not be able to meaningfully compress the file itself". Encryption can be applied effectually "inside" (i.e. to the plaintext) or ineffectually "outside" (to the encrypted container). I'm asking about "inside".

Comment: Additional thoughts - that I don't know the answers to… 1) Are you certain dd can properly copy Time Machine drives? Usually 3rd party tools try to copy all the hardlinks as individual files. [10TB makes me suspect this.] 2) You want it to remain useable in future - however since Big Sur, HFS can no longer be used for TM, so it's already 'not usable'.

Comment: @Tetsujin `dd` copies the raw disk, it doesn't care about any filesystems, content etc.

Comment: @nohillside -  ah, OK. Wasn't sure. Thanks.

Comment: @Tetsujin I’m sure, as I’ve been using “enter time machine” on this backup for a couple of years now. It works fine. It’s just … maximally large.